# Get all members (Props, fields) of a class, with in a class

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'm looking for an efficient way to get all properties/ fields of complex type which internally have Properties of another complex type.

*Example*

```
    class A
    {
        public int Id{get;set;}
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public List<string> Branch{get;set;}
        public BuildData build {get;set;}
        public SampleData sample {get;set;}
        public DummyData dData {get;set}
        //constructor
        public A(){}
    }

class BuildData{
    private string _buildData;
    public string param1{get;set;}
    public string[] paramArgs{get;set;}
}
class SampleData {
    public string Test{get;set;}
    public List<DummyData> dummyArgs{get;set;}
}

class DummyData {
    public int Val{get;set;}
    public string GUIData{get;set;}
}
```

I have to use `class A` & get all its members (fields, Props) which should also include members of other complex types such as DummyData, BuildData, SampleData.

I tried using Reflection but couldn't get all members.

```
    public void PrintProperties(object obj, ref String value)
    {

        if (obj == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
            var elems = propValue as IList;
            if (elems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in elems)
                {
                    PrintProperties(item, ref value);                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (property.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly)
                {
                    value += string.Format("*Name - {0}; Type - {1}*", property.Name, property.PropertyType);

                    PrintProperties(propValue, ref value);
}
                else
                {
                    value += string.Format("Name - {0}; defaultValue-{1}; Type - {2};", property.Name, propValue, property.PropertyType);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post some reflection code you tried to use

Comment: Combination of `recursion` with `GetProperties()` might fix problem. You can check property type for recursion. Do recusion if property is not simple type

Comment: Selecting what to navigate and what not to navigate is a problem in itself... `SampleData sample` is ok... But `Lazy<SampleData> lazySample`? Or `MyStruct? nullableStruct`

Comment: This feels like a XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you want to do this?